# Figuring out a frequency distribution for a vector of ints

Tags: c++, vector, distribution, frequency

I'm working on a project and I need to calculate the frequency distribution of a vector of ints that the user will type in. The distribution will be divided into 10 ranges. I just can't wrap my head around how to go through the vector properly and adjust the min and max values of each interval. Here's what I have written, which I know is way off (also, x is the name of the vector:

```
double range = max - min;
double interval = ceil(range / 10);
double frequency = 0.0;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = x.begin(); it < x.end(); it++)
{
    if (*it > min)
    {
        min = (min + interval);
        min = *it;
    }
    if (*it < max)
    {
        max = min + interval;
        max = *it;
    }
    if (*it >= min && *it <= max)
        ++frequency;
```

Comment: What you're looking to do is simply create a histogram.  Every time a value you get is within a certain range, add 1 to the "bucket" that holds that range.  Also, do you have to use a vector, or can you get away with a simple array?  Do you know the max and min of the distribution ahead of time, or do you need to calculate that by running through the vector a first time?

Comment: To _go through the vector properly_, change `it < x.end()` to `it != x.end()`.

Comment: @timrau thank you. I knew about ending iterators that way I just forgot to type it in!

Comment: The problem statement mentions adjusting the range for each interval, but not why the ranges are being adjusted. Is the goal for adjusting the ranges to end up with the same or nearly the same number of elements within each range? Are there duplicate values within the vector of integers?

Answer (score 0):

Divide the vector into a hashmap of vectors. Push back the values from the initial vector into the bucket set and the use std::min_element and std::max_element to find the smallest/largest from each range.

I would publish pseudo code but I am on my phone.